# Reading JSON Containing Emojis Into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, emoji

I receive UTF-8 encoded JSON files, similar to

```
[
    {
        "FieldA": "regular string 1",
        "FieldB": "... \ud83e\uddc0"
    },
    {
        "FieldA": "regular string 2",
        "FieldB": "... \ud83d\ude0d"
    }
]
```

I have tried to read it in using

```
df = pd.read_json(file_path, orient="columns", encoding="utf-8")
```

But I am unable to read in the emojis. Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json` and `json_normalize`:

```
import json 
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

j = [
    {
        "FieldA": "regular string 1",
        "FieldB": "... \ud83e\uddc0"
    },
    {
        "FieldA": "regular string 2",
        "FieldB": "... \ud83d\ude0d"
    }
]

s = json.dumps(j) # convert to string (serialize j to a json formatted string)
j2 = json.loads(s) # deserialize s to a python object
df = json_normalize(j2) # load to a dataframe

             FieldA FieldB
0  regular string 1  ... 
1  regular string 2  ...
```